# getting/setting String of FMUs with pyFMI

Tags: python, cython, fmi

I'm using pyFMI from Modelon to cosimulate between systemC and other tools, let say openModelica.

We tried to get and set inputs of type string but it seems not supported.
What we have in the description.xml file:

```
<ScalarVariable name="clock_timescale" valueReference="0" description="timescale of the internal clock manager" causality="parameter" variability="fixed" initial="exact">
    <String start ="NS" />
</ScalarVariable>
<ScalarVariable name="clock_period" valueReference="4" description="period of the internal clock manager" causality="parameter" variability="fixed" initial="exact">
    <Integer start ="20" />
</ScalarVariable>
```

In this piece of example, clock_period is an integer and clock_timescale is a string. If we have a quick look in the pyfmi log, we can see:

```
FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [logFmiCall][FMU status:OK] 
   fmi2GetInteger: clock_period = 20
FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [logFmiCall][FMU status:OK] 
   fmi2GetInteger: number_isready = 0
FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [logFmiCall][FMU status:OK] 
   fmi2GetInteger: number_port = 0
FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [logFmiCall][FMU status:OK] 
   fmi2GetInteger: result_port = 0
FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [logFmiCall][FMU status:OK] 
   fmi2GetInteger: result_isready = 0
FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [logFmiCall][FMU status:OK] 
   fmi2GetBoolean: reset = true
FMIL: module = Model, log level = 4: [logFmiCall][FMU status:OK] 
fmi2DoStep: currentCommunicationPoint = 0 communicationStepSize=20, noSetFMUStatePriorToCurrentPoint =1, internal time=0
```

We can see that the getter to clock_period is correctly called before the fmi2doStep but not the clock_timescale one.

Also, if we try to set the string, we obtain the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coordinator.py", line 56, in <module>
    model.set_string([0],['MS'])
  File "fmi.pyx", line 3555, in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelBase2.set_string (src/pyfmi/fmi.c:31090)
    NotImplementedError
```

Does anybody knows why it seems not supported ? Or if it is planned to be supported ? Is there a trick to make it work ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, setting and getting strings using PyFMI (version <= 2.2) is not supported and there is no trick to get it working unfortunately.

In the next version it will be supported though. The features are already implemented and available if the development version is used (building from source).

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer, we will move to the development version until the next release.
thanks !